# iOS where can i find cordova-1.8.0.js?

Tags: ios, cordova

I would like to update from `cordova-1.7.1.js` to `cordova-1.8.0.js` but there's no way i can find the latter

I followed the [API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html) on how to upgrade from  1.7.0 projects to 1.8.x but when it says

`2 - Copy the www/cordova-1.8.0.js file from the new project into your www folder, and delete your www/cordova-1.7.x.js file`

I can't find `cordova-1.8.0.js` nor the folder `www` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Cordova, there's a javascript folder under `/Users/xxxx/Documents/CordovaLib` that contains the js file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the likely answer is here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/ZgW8-v9ZITQ

Suggest downloading the version you want from github  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/tags and then looking in the ios subdirectory...

Comment: thank you for your time. that's exactly what i did, i installed the dmg from the ios subdirectory, but i still can't find the js file..

Comment: Note that the source code on github is available only starting from release 1.9.x